# Email marketing com informação via post?

Tags: php

Sei que parece impossível, mas uma líder aqui da empresa, teve a ideia de colocar um e-mail marketing já com uma informação que facilitará o cadastro aqui para o treinamento.

Ela, de forma original, havia dado a ideia de enviar o link para a inscrição do treinamento com o código da inscrição do treinamento via URL, onde assim eu conseguiria pegar via GET ao carregar a página. Só que ela deu uma preferência que ao clicar no botão de fazer cadastro, eu conseguisse pegar ele via POST?

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Então, nesse e-mail marketing, teria que ter um jeito de enviar um

```
<form method='post' name='frmCodPromocional'>
   <input type='hidden' value='cod_promocao'> 
   <input type='submit' name='btnEnviar'>
</form>
```

Onde `cod_promocao` seria o código que eu enviaria?

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, e se no POST passar  o código da inscrição?

Comment: teria que ser quando o cara clicar no link, carregar tipo
www.site.com.br/treinamento.php?idtrein=t005
Isso eu pegaria via GET, e pra pegar via POST
Essa a ideia, como fazer?

Comment: Não faz sentido, além de acredito eu não ser possível... O uso do `POST` é justamente para encodar os parâmetros da url, se não é necessário, qual o sentido?

Comment: Cara, tu entendeu minha pergunta certinho? acredito que não

Comment: @gabrielfalieri, reescrever sua pergunta, pq ta confusa.

Comment: @gabrielfalieri cara, a não ser que o café que eu tomei tenham incluido alguma substância intorpecente, creio que entendi, vc dá a entender(explicitamente) que haverá um link contendo parâmetros e valores, eles estão na url do próprio link, e que vc gostaria de pegar esse valor via post na página referida no link... Está correto?

Comment: exatamente, seu café não está zoado, nem o meu rs

Comment: Então man, para você pegar com `post` o método tem de ser `post` que é definido no `action`, `post` não envia via `url`, que faz isso é o método `get`. A funcionalidade de ambas não consiste no modo de "pegar" e sim de enviar, é no envio que se define o método, então se quer via `post` tem de enviar por `post`, e não vai ser no link ou URL, vai ser em um `form`...

Comment: Edição da pergunta com a resposta dessa mensagem

Comment: Você mesmo respondeu: só é possível utilizando o fomulário com `method=post`, porém, nem todos os clientes de e-mail suportam código HTML, eu não há garantias que o e-mail funcionaria perfeitamente. Se o link via GET funciona, continue com ele. Pelo o que entendi, apenas o código da inscrição será passado e isso não me parece um dado tão sensível que não poderia estar exposto na URL.

Comment: Beleza, vou deixar via get msm